# Reading & writing the registers of the PLC using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, tcp, plc

I am developing an app that we will give & receive the instruction from the PLC(programmable logic controller-- An industrial device microcontroller) using TCP/IP protocol.
Is there any library available or how can do perform the operation on reading & write over the device?

Answer (score 0):

There is [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/tcp_socket_connection/score) for Flutter, but it's not very popular and personally I have never used it.

Alternatively you could write your own library using the low level APIs in Dart.

Anyway, I wouldn't do this in flutter, as it is a frond-end framework.
This kind of comunication is usually done in other lower level and more powerful programming language.

Comment: Can you suggest how to do it in other programming languages as my application will be running on a tablet which will be connected to a Wifi router(having no internet) & plc also be connected to the router. Everything will be running locally only.

Comment: I would have suggested a simple client-server application with some microservices running on the server, but if all you have is a tablet, then your best bet is still trying to do it in Flutter/Dart in my opinion.